# Can I use .net 4.61 class library in the same project with .net 4.5 APS.net site?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.5, .net-4.6.1

I have a .net solution contain many projects, all of them are .net 4.5.
I have a situation that we need to use NuGet that depend on .net 4.61, so I decided to create a new class library .net 4.61 and include this NuGet in it. Project is build with no problems. but I'm not sure is that correct or not to have a solution with some projects .net 4.5 and others 4.61 ?

Answer (score 3):

Mixing projects built with different versions of the framework in a single solution is fine.

But a project build with an older version of the framework can't reference a project built with a newer version of the framework. For example a 4.6 project can't reference a 4.6.1 project.

The opposite is fine, a 4.6.1 can reference an 4.6

Here is an example from visual studio.

The 4.6 console app can reference the 4.5.1 library, but not the 4.6.1 library.

[image]